# Multiple lines in react-native-paper's Button component

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm trying to get a flex-based layout inside a button in React Native. Using `react-native-paper`, I'm able to make it look right on web with a `View` component inside. But, when I check the UI on Android, the button is empty. Is there a way to make this work?

```
<Button>
  <View>
    <Text>One</Text>
    <Text>Two</Text>
  </View>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use TouchableOpacity instand of Button

```
<TouchableOpacity >
  <View>
    <Text>One</Text>
    <Text>Two</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity >
```